# can't find curl-config on NixOS

Tags: nixos

I'm trying to install [vim-now-haskell](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now) on NixOS 17.09.

The installation fails with the exception

```
*** Installer requires 'curl-config'. Please install and try again.
*** Aborting...
```

Unfortunately [Search NixOS packages](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#curl-config) doesn't list any package for `curl-config`. It also isn't in installed `curl-7.56.1`.

I can hardly believe NixOS doesn't provide `curl-config`. Therefore I'm looking here for help to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the `curl.dev` output.

```
$ ls $(nix-build --no-out-link '<nixpkgs>' -A curl.dev)/bin
curl-config
```

The reason for this is to keep the closure size of anything the uses curl small. Normally Nixpkgs' `stdenv.mkDerivation` takes care of those details when processing the `buildInputs` attribute, but if you're not using Nixpkgs to build something you may have to do a bit more manual work.

Another way to get the `curl-config` command is `nix-shell -p curl`, which launches a shell that has the command in its environment.

```
[user@feb:~]$ nix-shell -p curl
[nix-shell:~]$ curl-config --version
libcurl 7.65.3
[nix-shell:~]$ exit
[user@feb:~]$
```

NixPkgs also has a `curlFull` package which has more features enabled, as can be seen by the number of packages in the closure of the runtime library output:

```
$ nix-store -q --requisites $(nix-build --no-out-link '<nixpkgs>' -A curl.out) | wc -l
6
$ nix-store -q --requisites $(nix-build --no-out-link '<nixpkgs>' -A curlFull.out) | wc -l
29
```

So for a more capable build of `curl`, use `curlFull.dev`.

Comment: `curlFull` doesn't provide curl-config either

Comment: With `curlFull` you also need the `dev` output; `nix-build '<nixpkgs>' -A curlFull.dev`

Comment: `nix-shell -p curlFull` is another method that lets you use `curl-config`