# In NixOS, how to run a Haskell executable from the command line?

Tags: haskell, nixos

I am attempting to run Haskell executables from the command line, following the example of [this blog](https://passingcuriosity.com/2008/literate-haskell-with-markdown-syntax-hightlighting/). My machine runs NixOS.

The blog is about compiling markdown literate haskell into html for publishing blog posts. One step in that process is to run the haskell program `hscolour` on the .lhs file to create a .mkd file with the code syntax-highlighted via html and css.

```
cat blah.lhs | hscolour -lit -css > blah.mkd
```

When I try to run this command, however, I get the following `command not found` error.

```
$ cat blah.lhs | hscolour -lit -css > blah.mkd                                                            
hscolour: command not found
```

I'm not sure whether this issue I'm having is specific to NixOS, or with making haskell executables available to the command line more broadly. **How do I make haskell executables such as `hscolour` available from the command line?**

---

I have tried running this command from within a `nix-shell` in which `hscolour` has been built. The `hscolour` command still was not found.

```
$ nix-shell -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (pkgs: with pkgs; [hscolour])"
$ cat functor-proofs.lhs | hscolour -li
hscolour: command not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things to know:

1. You don't need GHC, you just need the executable from hscolour, which you can obtain as `haskell.lib.justStaticExecutables haskellPackages.hscolour`.
2. The binary for hscolour is called `HsColour`, not `hscolour`.

To demonstrate:

```
$ nix-shell -p 'haskell.lib.justStaticExecutables haskellPackages.hscolour' --run 'HsColour --version'
HsColour 1.24
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll share an other approach I discovered shortly by looking for [an executable on NixOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222190/2789312).

```
$ `nix-build --no-out-link "<nixpkgs>"   -A haskellPackages.hscolour`/bin/HsColour --version                         
HsColour 1.24
```